# Selenium sendKeys doesnt input all text

Tags: c#, angularjs, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, angular-material

I'm trying to write e2e tests for our application based on angular and angular material. We are using chromedriver 2.16, selenium 2.46 and the newest protractor.net. The problem is, when I want to use sendKeys method, selenium doesn't send all of them all the time - it's random, sometimes it sends the whole value, sometimes 1-3 characters.

Here is the code:
1st with selenium

```
var nameInput = webDriver.FindElement(By.Id('SizeTemplateName'));
    nameInput.Click();
    nameInput.Clear();
    nameInput.SendKeys('some random value 123 456 789');
```

2nd with protractor.net

```
var nameInput = angularWebDriver.FindElement(NgBy.Model('vm.sizeTemplate.name'));
    nameInput.Click();
    nameInput.Clear();
    nameInput.SendKeys('some random value 123 456 789');
```

None of the approaches work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem. Try to use this

```
private static void sendKeys(IWebElement element, string text)
{
    element.Click();
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    foreach (char c in text)
    {
        actions.SendKeys(c.ToString())
            .Perform();
    }
}
```

Usage in code

```
sendKeys(nameInput, "some random value 123 456 789")
```

Comment: can you clarify what's the idea behind this working and the randomness of the op problem?